# Vagrant/Puppet - Provision Failing (MySQL Not Working)

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile, puppetlabs-mysql

I have tried different virtual boxes, I have changed tons of configurations (probably recreated, reloaded and reprovisioned 50-100 times) -- it has to do with the MySQL module from Puppet -- which is apparently working for tens of thousands of others, so something I am doing is wrong.

**VagrantFile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-puppet"

  # Was necessary
  #vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest

  # Networking
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Synced folders
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"

  # Update
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get -y update"

  # Provisioning
   config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                    (puppet module install example42-puppi; true)
                    (puppet module install example42-apache; true)
                    (puppet module install example42-php; true)
                    (puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib; true)
                    (puppet module install puppetlabs-mysql; true)
                    (puppet module install saz-vim; true)
                    (puppet module install saz-timezone; true)
                    (puppet module install puppetlabs-git; true)
                    (puppet module install tPl0ch-composer; true)
                     "
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
      puppet.facter = {
        "fqdn" => "development.mydomain.com",
        "aliases" => "*.development.mydomain.com",
        "hostname" => "www",
        "docroot" => '/var/www/html/',
      }
      puppet.hiera_config_path = "manifests/hiera.yaml"
      puppet.working_directory = "/etc/puppet"
    end
end
```

Puppet File: **default.pp**

```
###########################
# MySite Puppet Config    #
###########################
# OS          : Ubuntu 14 #
# Database    : MySQL 5   #
# Web Server  : Apache 2  #
# PHP version : 5.4       #
###########################

# Vim
class { 'vim': }

# Set Timezone
class { 'timezone':
    timezone => 'America/Chicago',
}

# Puppi
class { 'puppi': }

# Apache setup
class { "apache":
  puppi        => true,
  puppi_helper => "myhelper",
}

apache::vhost { $fqdn :
  docroot => $docroot,
  server_name => $fqdn,
  serveraliases => $aliases,
  priority            => '',
  template            => 'apache/virtualhost/vhost.conf.erb',
}

apache::module { 'rewrite': }
apache::module { 'headers': }

# PHP Extensions
class {"php":}

php::module { ['xdebug', 'mysql', 'curl', 'gd', 'mcrypt']:
  notify => Service['apache2']
}

# MySQL Server
class { '::mysql::server':
  package_ensure  => present,
  root_password     => '[root_password]',
  override_options  => { 'mysqld' => { 'default_time_zone' => 'America/Chicago' } },
}

class { 'mysql::client':}

mysql::db { '[db_name]':
  user     => '[user]',
  password => '[password]',
  host     => 'localhost',
  grant    => ['ALL'],
  charset => 'utf8',
}

exec { "database_import":
  timeout => 300,
  command => "/bin/gzip -dc /vagrant/manifests/provision.sql.gz | /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p[root_password]";
}

mysql::db { '[db_test]':
  user     => '[user_test]',
  password => '[password_test]',
  host     => 'localhost',
  grant    => ['ALL'],
  charset => 'utf8',
  sql  => "/var/www/test/db-schema.sql",
}

# Install Composer components
include composer

composer::exec { 'install':
    cmd                  => 'install',  # REQUIRED
    cwd                  => '/var/www', # REQUIRED
    dev                  => true, # Install dev dependencies
}

# Git
include git

# MySite Setup
file { $docroot:
  ensure  => 'directory',
}

$writeable_dirs = ["${docroot}cache/", "${docroot}cache/css/", "${docroot}cache/css/js/"]

file { $writeable_dirs:
  ensure => "directory",
  mode   => '0777',
  require => File[$docroot],
}

file { '/var/www/cl/':
  ensure  => directory
}

file { 'errors_log':
  path    => "/var/www/cl/errors.log",
  ensure  => present,
  mode    => 0777,
}

# Cron Jobs
cron { thirty_minutes:
  command => "/usr/bin/php ${docroot}cl-load.php crons/thirty_minutes/",
  user  => root,
  minute => '*/30'
}

cron { hourly:
  command => "/usr/bin/php ${docroot}cl-load.php crons/hourly/",
  user  => root,
  hour => '*',
  minute => 0,
}

cron { four_hours:
  command => "/usr/bin/php ${docroot}cl-load.php crons/four_hours/",
  user  => root,
  hour => '*/4',
  minute => 0,
}

cron { daily:
  command => "/usr/bin/php ${docroot}cl-load.php crons/daily/",
  user  => root,
  monthday => '*',
  hour => '0',
  minute => 0,
}
```

Here is the error message I am receiving (the first):

```
==> ==> default: Error: Could not start Service[mysqld]: Execution of '/sbin/start mysql' returned 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Puppet is trying to import the database before installing the MySQL server package.

Keep in mind that Puppet don't care about which resources you write first, if you need to manage something in a specific order you have to declare relationships explicitly. So in your case the following statement:

```
exec { "database_import":
  timeout => 300,
  command => "/bin/gzip -dc /vagrant/manifests/provision.sql.gz | /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p[root_password]",
  require => Class['::mysql::server']
}
```

Could set the correct order for that resource. Possibly you'll need to declare additional relationships in a similar manner.

Comment: Hey, added that, realized there was 1 Warning before it: `==> default: Error: Could not start Service[mysqld]: Execution of '/sbin/start mysql' returned 1:`